# jQuery and document.ready() firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it is quite a common issue, but even with research I was not able to understand what goes wrong in my call to document.ready() Javascript function.

For some reason, it gets called twice, even when I don't execute anything else than an alert.

As I said in the title, I am using jQuery, and figured something could come from $(function(){}), so I removed any execution in there as well. Nothing changes, document.ready() is still called twice.

What can be the origin of this issue? How to troubleshoot/solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Here's the code I've tried :

```
$(function(){
    //$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    //getTableEntity("organisation", "getentitytable", "#testtable");
    //standardDataTable('#tableOrga');
    alert("document.ready");
});
```

Edit : I know I'm using the same function twice. Putting everything in one function doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: post your code that you tried. and `document.ready()` should `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @GabrielTheron http://jsfiddle.net/tdgM8/16/ working here? `:)` cannot se any 2 alerts?

Comment: Yep, it's working in jsfiddle

Comment: This code you've shown us works exactly as it should. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: :) Magic :P you need to check if there is something wrong within your code! might be called twice i.e. from another function check on click and stuff. Like in example you have `$(function(){...` and `$(document).ready(){...`

Comment: In the code you should see both `$(function...)` and `$(document).ready...` called. So in all you should have 4 method calls if document ready is fired twice. Is that what you see?

Comment: Yes but actually, $(document).ready can be declared in several places, it will only be called once (or so I've read at least)

Comment: The event will only **fire** once but for each event **every** attached handler (in the above case two) will be executed

Comment: Yes, but that is not an issue as I've placed the alert in only one of them. The event itself is fired twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you use a template-Engine such smarty or .net or something else? It could be that there is a double script source for jquery. Then there are side effects.

Comment: I was calling the javascript in the {% block javascripts %} of my Twig, which was probably calling it twice. When placed in the body, it fires only once now. Thank you!

Comment: This answer saved my butt

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the dom is ready with this code. Place code in your javascript source file.

```
// If the DOM is already ready
if ( jQuery.isReady ) {
// Execute the function immediately
fn.call( document, jQuery );
} // ...
```

Comment: That makes no change, which means jQuery is ready from the start.

Answer (score 1):

should use one of them... and put your code on one of the following jquery function

```
$(function(){
    //$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //getTableEntity("organisation", "getentitytable", "#testtable");
    //standardDataTable('#tableOrga');
    alert("document.ready");
});
```

`$(function(){`  is equal to `$(document.ready)`

Read here on [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 0):

i think this demo will help you

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#test1').appendTo('#test2');
        console.log(1);
    })
</script>
<div id="test1">
<script>
    $(function(){
        console.log(2);     
    });
</script>
</div>

<div id="test2"></div>
```

the console.log(2) will fire twice.